# 16-bit grayscale image handling with custom image provider in PySide2

Tags: python, pyside2, qimage

I have a PySide2 project where I've defined a custom image provider, relaying images from a camera to an image control in QtQuick. The images are 16-bit grayscale arrays, so I'd prefer to simply relay this image data directly to the display. Raw image data (self.image) is processed and converted to a QImage via the following line:

```
img = QImage(self.image, w, h, line_len, QImage.Format_Grayscale8)
```

This, of course, requires that I resample the data from 16 bit (ushort) to 8 bit (uint) prior to display. Instead, I tried calling directly the 16-bit format:

```
img = QImage(self.image, w, h, line_len, QImage.Format_Grayscale16)
```

But this throws an error:

```
AttributeError: type object 'PySide2.QtGui.QImage' has no attribute 'Format_Grayscale16'
```

I'm running PySide2 version 5.13.2, and the Qt documentation says that Format_Grayscale16 was available from Qt 5.13 (not to mention it seems to exist in my local QImage class, since PyCharm gives me the auto-complete option). What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: what is output of `python -c "from PySide2.QtCore import qVersion; print('Qt version', qVersion())"`?

Comment: It does not throw me this error, it could provide a [mre].

Comment: The output of the command gives: `Qt version 5.12.5`. Hmm maybe that's the problem? Is there a particular package that needs to get updated to bring me up to 5.13?

Comment: I think pycharm is using the wrong python since if you say you are using pyside2 5.13.2 then you should have got Qt 5.13.2, what do you get when you run 
`python -c "from PySide2 import __version__; print('PySide2 version', __version__)"`? I have tested it by installing that version and I obtained that pyside2 and qt5 have the same version (I used pip for the installation)

Comment: Yeah it looks like my qt package version is out of date, or somehow out of sync. I'm using Anaconda and issuing a `conda list pyside2` reports pyside2 version 5.13.2; issuing a `conda list qt` reports qt version 5.12.5 (all of these are pulling from conda-forge). Issuing a `conda update -c conda-forge qt` reports a bunch of dependencies out of date too, so I'll give that a try on my test bench and report the results. Thanks for the pointers here!

Comment: Hmm, Anaconda, ... I was suspecting it. Anaconda developers compile PySide2 with different versions of Qt that do not match, for example Qt developers have established a rule: pyside2 version matches Qt version.

Comment: It looks like the Conda repos are stuck at qt version 5.12.5. :-( So: pip it is!

Comment: Sorry I'm having trouble getting qt to update... after updating PySide2 to 5.15.0 via pip, my qt version is still stuck at 5.12.5. I also tried updating PyQt5 to 5.15.0 but still the qt version remains the same. Pip doesn't seem to know about a package called "qt" - what am I missing here?

Comment: recommendation: Don't use anaconda, create a virtualenv and have pycharm use the virtualenv python

Comment: that did the trick - THANK YOU!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is recommended that when compiling a specific version of PySide2 then the same version of Qt is used, but that is not a mandatory rule so if the pyside2 that is used is not officially provided then the previous recommendation was not necessarily met. If you want to know the version of pyside2 and qt you can use the following commands, respectively:

```
python -c "from PySide2 import __version__; print('PySide2 version', __version__)"
python -c "from PySide2.QtCore import qVersion; print('Qt version', qVersion())"
```

For PyQt5 you can use:

```
python -c "from PyQt5.QtCore import PYQT_VERSION_STR; print('PyQt5 version', PYQT_VERSION_STR)"
python -c "from PyQt5.QtCore import QT_VERSION_STR; print('Qt version', QT_VERSION_STR)"
```

As the OP points out in the comments, he is using anaconda which compiles manually so it does not meet the initial recommendation (uses Qt 5.12.5). So the solution is to use official PySide2 using pip:

```
python -m pip install pyside2
```